# Make a coordinate plane

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, math, ipod-touch

How can I make a coordinate plane view controller in Xcode? I've tried to use OPENGL but it hasn't been working. Do I have to draw lines individually? Make it recursively called so that it keeps making a certain amount of lines?

Answer (score 1):

You will want to take into account what you will be doing to the coordinate plan. Can you move the plane? Can you zoom in?

You will want to set up `centerLocation` and `scale` variables. `centerLocation` denotes your center and this is where you will draw a vertical and a horizontal bold line for the axes. `scale` denotes how many pixels per unit you want to have. You can the default to something like 10. You can use this variable to control zooming.

If you want to use the plane for something like graphing functions, the bare minimum you need is the axes. You can use the scale to find out where "points" are in your grid. Making functions for this is useful.

If you want to draw grid lines, what you can do is simply check the leftmost bound of the grid using the `centerLocation.x` as an offset and then iterate through the pixels by increments of `scale` and simply draw a vertical line at each point you come across until you get to the end. Same for horizontal lines, except you can start at the top, offset `centerLocation.y`, and add a horizontal line in increments of `scale` until your counter is greater than the height of the screen.

Comment: if i were to graph the linear equation, y=2x+4 how would i do that? And how would I take user input to graph something?

Comment: or the quadratic equation, y=x^2+2x+4?

Comment: Run through the bottom of the screen pixel by pixel. For each pixel, apply the equation (you'll have to have some sort of parser for it), and make sure that the pixels correspond to the correct "point" using the scale and centerLocation or whatever offset you have. It's really simple.